# Работа с кэшем. Удалить данные из браузера

Tags: php, html, webbrowser

Аватар каждого пользователя имеет свой адрес: `http://example.com/avatars/[id_пользователя].jpg`

При загрузке нового аватара меняется только содержимое файла, а ссылка остаётся такой же. И тут происходит проблема, по окончанию загрузки пользователь видит не новый аватар, а старый, так как браузер выдаёт ему кэш.

Вопрос: Как при загрузке аватара удалить его старый кэш из браузера?

Comment: `[id_пользователя].jpg ` замените на `[hash].jpg`.Нe светите реальные id пользователя из базы

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можете добавить версию аватара.
[http://example.com/avatars/[id_пользователя].jpg?v=1](http://example.com/avatars/[id_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F].jpg?v=1)

Или же прописать соответствующие headers при выдаче аватара

```
  header ("Expires:  Sun, 01 Aug 2000 07:00:00 GMT"); 
  header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
  header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
  header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Comment: Вы решили аватар средствами php выдавать? :)

Comment: Я лишь добавил возможный вариант.